# UIDataPicker into TextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, datapicker

I wrote this code for a `UIDataPicker` into `TextField`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateTextField: UITextField!


    @IBAction func textFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

        let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: ViewController.datePickerValueChanged, forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

    }

    func datePickerValueChanged(sender:UIDatePicker) {
        let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.MediumStyle
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle
        dateTextField.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
```

but I have this error:

> Type 'ViewController' has no member 'datePickerValueChanged'

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dataPickerValueChanged or datePickerValueChanged?
```

Check your code

Comment: did you change that in your code as well? Also, instead of ViewController.datePickerValueChanged, maybe try self.datePickerValueChanged. I have rarely seen the use of class name like that @Ilmionome456